# Refactoring Angular 2 project for MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I started to an Angular2 project weeks ago by following the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial. I kept developing the project with the structure of these tutorial. Now I have hundreds line of code including routers, rest services, etc.

After all these steps, now I have to use MEAN stack for the project. I found this tutorial http://thejackalofjavascript.com/developing-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-0/ but now I am messed up with the structure. I am also worried about will NodeJS routing and my current routing(angular2) conflict.

Can you advise me about how to move whole project into mean stack without changing its structure?

Answer (score 0):

May I propose you a different approach in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373515/7564182), just start after the @angular/cli-step.