# Which is the best way(method) to host an mean application which is developed using Nodejs,Angularjs,Mongodb

Tags: hosting, mean-stack

I am new to this Web development. I need to know the different ways in which the application i developed can be hosted

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough checklist with links:

- For a MEAN-Stack you start with the [node.js Installation](https://nodejs.org/en/), which delivers the command framework for the rest.
- When you start from scratch, my recommendation for the next step is to install [Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html) with the @angular/cli Package.
- When you are familiar with the FrontEnd in Angular 2, you can install the [expressjs server](http://expressjs.com/) following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356959/7564182).
- So the backend and the frontend are there, but they have to talk to each other with e.g. the [routing in express](http://expressjs.com/de/guide/routing.html) on the backend and the [http client of angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html).
- When you don't have it, you have to install [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community) before you can connect via [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) from express server (backend) to the database.

Others may propose other ways or even ready to use packages, which I've also used, but I'm using this approach first to learn and test on every step before to move forward.