# how to make a simple form in mean.js

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs

Hello am actually working on my final year project.Am trying to make a web app with mean stack.i have been following online examples to build what i required.
Unfortunately am unable to make a form that can capture value and store to mongodb
please help thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps to setup your environment, which are explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373515/7564182). And for each technique there is a lot to learn and test.